# ng-disabled not allowing enter more than one text in input text box inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm sharing a fiddle where I have tried to ng-disable to disable all the input text boxes that have a value in it,but when I try to enter a value in a text box that dosen't have a value it is disabling by entering only a single character.Has anybody faced a similar issue,,please share your thoughts..

[Disabling input text box inside ng-repeat](http://plnkr.co/edit/a4CEmBZa44WzpVmiB6bZ?p=preview)

```
  <input type="text" ng-model="valuesForOutputs[item.name][i]" 
                                        ng-disabled="valuesForOutputs[item.name][i]" required   name="value"
                                               placeholder="Enter value">
```

Comment: So, what is the problem? If you tell it to disable fields with a value, then if you enter a value for into an empty field, it should become disabled. Note that a 'truthy' value is a string of length > 0, so a single character constitutes.

Comment: I want to enter more than 1 character

Comment: so just use, ng-disabled="valuesForOutputs[item.name][i].length > 1"

Comment: Ok, and after you enter text, do you want it to become disabled?

Comment: No @GPicazo .I want the text box to remain open

Comment: I've added a solution and linked a fork of your plunker that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are wanting to disable off of the initial state of the output values, but then you modify it and that changes what is disabled/enabled.

Instead, you should create an original copy of the values and use that to disable. Then update the values `$scope.valuesForOutputs` which tracks the current values.

Try adding the following:

```
var origValuesForOutputs = angular.copy($scope.valuesForOutputs);

$scope.isDisabled = function(output, month) {
   var val = origValuesForOutputs[output][month];
   return val && val.length;
 };
```

And change the ng-disabled to:

```
ng-disabled="isDisabled(item.name, i)"
```

Here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/2AeNujzK2XLtBzdHbLNS?p=preview

Comment: Thanks.I have added a validation for my input text box to accept only numbers.Its not firing up can you pls check here http://plnkr.co/edit/y4IA2a9EbuUlwkjqXPMt?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can use this trick with ng-init:

```
<td ng-repeat="i in months" 
    ng-init="wasEmpty=!valuesForOutputs[item.name][i]">{{valuesForOutputs[item.name][i]}}
    <input type="text" ng-model="valuesForOutputs[item.name][i]"
        ng-disabled="valuesForOutputs[item.name][i] && !wasEmpty" 
        required name="value" placeholder="Enter value">
</td>
```